# SSL_Connection failed with SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL with errno=2?

Tags: sockets, openssl

SSL_Connect API is failing with return value 5 errno=2. 
can any one help me in how to trace the same? can any one let me know what could cause this issue?

OS: Windows 2003 Std Sp2 32 bit

Comment: Have you tried calling SSL_get_error() to get an explanation?

Comment: My apology. 
The question which I had posted is not appropriate. 

just correcting below:
ssl_connect is giving SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL with "errno=2". I am not getting why this is happening. i am using local authentication and verify callback function was not called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following APIs to check the error further as it will store the error as a string in buf.

1. `value = ERR_get_error();`
2. `ERR_error_string_n(value,buf,sizeof buf);`

Furthermore, I also received this error when I added `"SET_MODE_AUTO_RETRY"` to CTX object and created an SSL object. I removed it and made changes to retry on my own in case of some error after some delay.

Another check you can do is what port value are you using? If it is not 443 then please try with 443; it may help.

I am also new to this so just sharing what I tried in order to resolve these issues.

Comment: please don't invent words like _u_ :-)